# access all_mview or user_mviews from app code

Tags: oracle, view

I need to access the user_mviews or all_mviews table to get meta information about materialized view in my app. Which grants are necessary to read the user_mviews table?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

by default all users can read the `user_mviews` and `all_mviews` views since the SELECT right is granted to `public`:

```
SQL> SELECT grantee, privilege, table_name
  2    FROM dba_tab_privs
  3   WHERE table_name IN ('USER_MVIEWS', 'ALL_MVIEWS');

GRANTEE  PRIVILEGE  TABLE_NAME
-------- ---------- ------------
PUBLIC   SELECT     USER_MVIEWS
PUBLIC   SELECT     ALL_MVIEWS
```

If for some reason this grant has been removed, you would need to regrant the rights to either `public` or a specific user (with a DBA account):

```
GRANT SELECT ON user_mviews TO <user>;
```

---

*Edit:* By definition, [`USER_MVIEWS`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_4371.htm#REFRN26139) describes materialized views owned by the current user while [`ALL_MVIEWS`](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14237/statviews_1105.htm#i1582466) describes the materialized views accessible to the current user (the user needs to be granted SELECT on the mview either directly or through a role).

Comment: the problem that I have is that I'm able to do a select on this table but without any result rows.

Comment: If you're connecting as a different user than the owner of the mview, it won't appear in `USER_MVIEWS`, and will only appear in `ALL_MVIEWS` if you have permissions against the mview itself. Make sure select on the mview is granted to the user you're connecting as.

Comment: hi alex, this solved my problem! please write you answer as an answer so that I can upvote it and accept as final answer.

Comment: @lewap: Vincent's answered your original question, I've just addressed the follow-up. Unless you plan to edit the question I'd go with this as the answer. Glad I could help though.